# How to call a method from a Server endpoint class with websockets in java?

Tags: java, java-websocket

I am using `org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server` and `javax.websocket`. After starting the server I want to call the broadcast method. Is there any way to interact with the `ServerEndpoint class` from the other classes in the program while the server is running?

The **Server class**:

```java
public class WebsocketServer{

    private int port;
    private Server server;

    public WebsocketServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        server = new Server("localhost", this.port, "/websockets", ExampleServerEndpoint.class);
    }

    public void startServer() throws Exception{
        server.start();
    }

    public void stopServer() throws Exception{
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

The **Server Endpoint class**:

```java
@ServerEndpoint( value = "/exmple")
public class ExampleServerEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {}

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {}

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {}

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session) {}

    public void broadcast() {
        //Broadcast a message
    }
}
```